# How could I pass a parameter to a WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, database

The title of the question might be misleading. I need to fetch a attribute from XML file. And then, search the Database with the attribute. Since the value of attribute is dynamic, I have to try send it as parameter to WHERE Clause of SQL scripts. However, it always return invalid column error.

Here is a part of the codes:

```
string umail = "";
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\1.xml");

var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("AdminUserDB.dbo.U_User")
        select (string)c.Element("URI");

foreach (string em in q)
    umail = em;

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=AdminUserDB;Persist Security Info=True; uid=sa;pwd=pwd");
cn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.U_User WHERE URI=umail", cn);
```

.....

Is there any other methods for this operation?

Thanks

SuT

Comment: You are getting the error because in the part `URI=umail`, the database is expecting the `umail` to be a column, but you intended to have a value there, so you need to use `@umail` which identifies it to `SqlDataAdapter` that it is a parameter in the query - which will be replaced before it is sent to the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use parameters:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.U_User WHERE URI=@umail", cn);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@umail", umail);
```